# Ruby 1.8.5 I can't install any gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation

When I tried to install any gem like, for example, json
gem install json -V
it show message like this

```
GET 301 Moved Permanently: http://gems.rubyforge.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
GET 302 Moved Temporarily: https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
GET 200 OK: https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz
GET 302 Moved Temporarily: https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
GET 200 OK: https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz
GET 302 Moved Temporarily: https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
GET 304 Not Modified: https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/latest_specs.4.8.gz
GET 302 Moved Temporarily: https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-1.1.5-x86-linux.gemspec.rz
GET 200 OK: https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-1.1.5-x86-linux.gemspec.rz
GET 302 Moved Temporarily: https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-2.0.2.gemspec.rz
GET 200 OK: https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-2.0.2.gemspec.rz
GET 301 Moved Permanently: http://gems.rubyforge.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-1.1.5-x86-linux.gemspec.rz
GET 302 Moved Temporarily: https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-1.1.5-x86-linux.gemspec.rz
GET 200 OK: https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-1.1.5-x86-linux.gemspec.rz
GET 301 Moved Permanently: http://gems.rubyforge.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-2.0.2.gemspec.rz
GET 302 Moved Temporarily: https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-2.0.2.gemspec.rz
GET 200 OK: https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/json-2.0.2.gemspec.rz


Installing gem json-2.0.2
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/bin/ruby terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(__chk_fail+0x41)[0x76b3a1]
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-linux/syck.so(rb_syck_mktime+0x501)[0x11a601]
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-linux/syck.so(yaml_org_handler+0x838)[0x11af18]
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-linux/syck.so(syck_defaultresolver_node_import+0x3f)[0x11b27f]
```

This happend with almost all gems 
how I could fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ruby 1.8.5 was released more than ten years ago. Whereas the JSON 2.0.2 is just a few days old. I would be very surprised if they were compatible. Why do you work with such an old version of Ruby? Is it an option to update to a current Ruby version (2.2 - 2.3)? Or you might want to  consider installing a version of the JSON gem that released at the same time that your old Ruby version (0.4.3 for example)...

Comment: It is highly possible that gems for ruby 1.8.5 are not supported, because 1.8.5 is not a suuported version of Ruby. I would recommend using something newer (2.3, the current version would be the best one).

Comment: Im working on a Centoos 5 sever which has that Ruby version intalled with some script running. I will install a most updated ruby interpreter. Thanks for the comments.